# Como realmente entender Streams?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

Trabalho faz um tempo com C# e .NET e várias vezes já vi o uso de streams por aí para leitura de arquivos, escrita de resposta HTML, upload de arquivos e etc. Acontece que eu até hoje não entendi o que realmente é um stream, quando eles devem ser usados e nem como funciona.

Por exemplo, pra ler um arquivo usamos o seguinte:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(caminhoArquivo))
{
    string conteudo = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Outro exemplo é o upload de dados pra um blob do Microsoft Azure

```
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(caminhoArquivo))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);
}
```

E um outro exemplo, que não envolve arquivos, é escrever o conteudo de uma resposta HTTP num middleware do OWIN. Pesquisando um pouco sobre streams achei o seguinte:

> Temos uma classe abstrata que representa uma sequência de bytes na qual podemos realizar operações de leitura e escrita. Essa classe abstrata é chamada de Stream.

Dessa forma um stream é uma sequencia de bytes? Mesmo assim, quando isso deve ser usado? Por que nesses casos que eu citei usamos streams? No caso da resposta HTTP é até um pouco mais dificil entender, não poderiamos somente escrever o texto da resposta inves de um stream?

Comment: O stream é uma maneira de se tratar um conteúdo aos poucos, sem colocá-lo inteiro de uma vez na memória. É um fluxo de dados. Esse pelo menos é o meu entendimento, de maneira bem simplificada.

Comment: Então @bfavaretto, a ideia de usar streams é ao inves de colocar um volume muito grande de dados na memória de uma vez, carregar e tratar aos poucos sem deixar o conteúdo todo na memória?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Quase isso. *Stream* é uma sequência de dados, de elementos. Podem ser *bytes*, o mais comum, mas não necessariamente. Os elementos individuais podem ser objetos mais complexos ou mais simples, como o *bit*. Se formos traduzir a palavra, provavelmente chamaríamos de fluxo contínuo. É apenas um conceito.

Fluxo é a palavra-chave aí. O *stream* é criado justamente para evitar ter que lidar como o todo. Com ele é possível ir manipulando os dados desejados sob demanda.

Com o *stream* a aplicação trabalha com um modelo de conexão sempre. O código inicia a conexão abrindo o *stream* e pode usá-lo até que ele seja fechado pelo código, eventualmente decidido através de sinalização recebida durante o processo. A conexão não precisa ser um mecanismo externo, basta ter uma coleção de dados.

## Vantagens

Esses dados podem estar disponíveis como um todo ou não. Ele pode vir/ir aos poucos resolvendo um potencial problema de sobrecarga de memória (de qualquer tipo), congestionamento e ausência temporária de transmissão. Enquanto o *stream* estiver aberto e não der nenhuma indicação que ele terminou ele pode fornecer dados novos mesmo que uma espera seja necessária.

Outra vantagem é que não precisa saber como a informação vem/vai, não importa a fonte ou alvo. Você não precisa saber que o *stream* funciona de uma determinada forma. Se a fonte/alvo de dados é um arquivo em disco, na memória, ou objeto na memória, uma transmissão da rede em qualquer protocolo, uma conexão de banco de dados, uma comunicação com outro processo, um algoritmo que gere estes dados sob demanda (números randômicos, por exemplo) ou outra forma, isto é problema da fonte/alvo de dados com o *stream*.

O programa que vai consumir o *stream* não precisa saber como os dados chegam até ele. Por isso ela é chamada de classe abstrata (nada a ver com `abstract` de OOP, ainda que este mecanismo seja usado em linguagens OO para implementá-lo). Você não precisa saber a implementação concreta da fonte/alvo de dados. Também não precisa saber qual é o modo usado para o fornecimento de dados. Diversos mecanismos podem ser usados dentro dele sem que o código consumidor do *stream* precise estar ciente.

Talvez um exemplo citado que caiba explicação é a geração de randômicos. Ao gerar números randômicos não significa que o gerador seja um *stream*. Assim como gerar uma *string* também não o é. O *stream* encapsula dados. Então um gerador de randômicos pode ser a fonte de dados do *stream* mas não o *stream* em si. Não podemos chamar qualquer sequência de elementos de *stream*, precisa atender ao protocolo estabelecido por ele.

Um *stream* pode inclusive manipular dados em certas situações se houver algum motivo para seu mecanismo prover algo assim. Ainda assim o programador não precisa saber internamente como e porque ele faz isto, só precisa entender como os dados vêm e vão através deles.

## APIs que aceitam *stream*

Em tese se uma API quiser fornecer uma forma de trabalhar com dados sem o *stream* não há problema. Uma resposta HTTP poderia trabalhar direto com o texto, mas perderia todas estas vantagens citadas acima. Por exemplo, [`System.IO.File.WriteAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_) não trabalha com *stream*.

Obviamente que se a API só aceita comunicação através de *streams* você terá que fazê-lo desta forma. No **geral** só tem vantagens em usar desta forma.

## Desvantagem

Talvez alguém possa colocar que há desvantagem por ter uma camada a mais, que aumenta ligeiramente a complexidade e consumo de processamento. Mas são coisas muito pequenas que não costumam ser relevantes perto das vantagens apresentadas pelo seu uso. Vou ressaltar que o custo extra do seu uso é mínimo em todos os sentidos.

## Um exemplo real de implementação

Talvez analisar o código da classe [`Stream`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/Stream.cs,f956b0c07e86df64) possa ajudar (ou atrapalhar :)) entender seu funcionamento. Note que ela é apenas a base para as classes que realmente fornecem *streams* concretos, que sabem como lidar em determinadas fontes/alvos. Talvez seja interessante analisar o código de algumas classes que herdam dela, como a [`FileStream`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/FileStream.cs,e23a38af5d11ddd3).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).