# MemoryStream vs Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, stream

Qual seria a principal diferença entre os dois?

Há vantagens no ganho de performance?

Para utilização web, qual o mais indicado?

Estou utilizando para "ler" um *array* `Byte[]`:

```
private void bytetoStrem(byte[] pdf)
{
    Stream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(pdf);

    pdfViewer1.LoadDocument(pdfStream);
}
```

Comment: Como o método principal (que chama esse `bytetoStrem`) carrega esse array de bytes do PDF? É uma API que retorna para ele? Ou você lê de uma pasta no próprio servidor?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Qual seria a principal diferença entre os dois?

O [`Stream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0) é uma classe abstrata base para todos os [*streams* (definição mais completa)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49831/101)  que podem existir, assim você pode codificar algoritmos que precisem de *stream* sem saber de onde eles vêm e vão.

Já [`MemoryStream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0) é uma classe concreta, obviamente derivada de `Stream` como pode ser observado no código da pergunta, e trabalha com fluxos de dados na memória bruta.

> Há vantagens no ganho de performance?

Em ralação a que? Entre um deles? Como um é abstrato sequer pode ser comparado. Se for com outros precisa ver a implementação de cada um, depende do hardware onde ele trabalha.

> Para utilização web, qual o mais indicado?

Entre os dois sempre será a classe concreta já que a abstrata faz nada. Se quiser comparar com outras coisas não faz sentido analisar o uso para web, desenvolvimento para web é algo genérico demais para definir algo.

Entre os *streams* existentes no .NET não vejo outro que poderia ser usado para web especificamente, mas no geral sim. É possível usar algum outro de terceiros ou desenvolver o seu próprio. A documentação *linkada* acima tem todas as classes do .NET que herdam de `Stream`.

## Seu caso

Se o que está fazendo funciona e atende todos os requisitos que deseja em todas situações, ou seja, se é o certo, ok. Me parece que este caso está ok, está carregando um PDF com API específica e jogando isso na memória conforme essa API permite. Eu vou chutar que não é necessário ser um *stream* no caso, mas não sei se a API do visualizador de PDF tem outra forma de acessar. Se a intenção é enviar diretamente para outro local então pode ser que outro seja mais adequando, mas pela pergunta não temos como saber.

O problema em geral ocorre porque as pessoas não leem a documentação, não entendem pontos colaterais e não testam todas situações que pode ocorrer, em geral a pessoa testa para funcionar, quando o certo é testar para não funcionar e descobrir onde pode dar problema e evitá-lo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 14):

`Stream` nada mais é do que a classe base e abstrata (ou seja, não pode ser instanciada) para todos os demais tipos de `Stream` disponíveis.

`MemoryStream` é uma das implementações de `Stream`, que provê uma forma de você armazenar um *Buffer* (dados em bytes crus) em memória.

Na [página de documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) você encontrará diversas implementações nativas do próprio framework .NET, tais como:

- `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream`: Encapsula um outro `Stream`, (des)compactando as informações deste;
- `System.IO.FileStream`: Provê manipulação (leitura, gravação, navegação) em um *buffer* apontando para um arquivo do sistema de arquivos;
- `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream`: Provê manipulação de *buffer* da rede;

Answer (score 8):

Como já dito anteriormente, o STREAM é uma classe abstrata. MEMORYSTREAM é uma classe derivada dessa classe, como também o FILESTREAM.

Eu costumo usar MEMORYSTREAM quando estou trabalhando com arquivos pequenos e não vejo problemas em mantê-los integralmente em memoria (MEMORYSTREAM). Ex. uma foto, ou algo assim. 
Já quando se vai trabalhar com arquivos grandes, imagine um vídeo de 200MB por exemplo, é bem mais aconselhável que se use um FILESTREAM, que ele vai lendo e transmitindo o arquivo aos poucos, sem carrega-lo totalmente para a memória.
Espero ter ajudado a esclarecer a sua dúvida.