# Por que std::cout utiliza o <<?

Tags: c++, console

Sou muito iniciante na linguagem, talvez esteja sendo apressado, mas gostaria de entender por que `std::cout` e `std::cin` utilizam respectivamente `<<` e `>>` diferente da sua "linguagem mãe" C, que utiliza os comandos `printf("");` e `scanf("",%);`

Tenho conhecimento básico de C, porém vi que para as coisas que pretendo desenvolver, o C++ é mais indicado, programo por pura diversão.

Atualmente em C++ só consigo escrever coisas no console e utilizar comandos que derivam do C, como `if`, `for` e etc.

Mas desde que comecei a ver programadores codificando em C++ isso me deixa com uma pulga atrás da orelha.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Porque os criadores da linguagem acharam que esse operador seria interessante para indicar "um pedaço de um *stream*". Era o que visualmente dava alguma indicação de ser um [*stream*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49831/101), estava disponível para esse tipo de objeto e pareceu uma boa ideia.

Note que só o `cout` e `cin` (na verdade esses tipos são uma capa em cima dos tipos reais que manipulam o *stream*) ter esse operador ajuda pouco, os tipos que você usar junto precisam ter esse operador também para conseguir criar o *stream*. O mecanismo de *stream* é bem complexo e requer bastante estudo.

A ideia é que o resultado desse operador seja sempre uma forma formatada de apresentação do objeto que está sendo usado no *stream*, então o objeto fornece o jeito que ele deve aparecer, e não precisa ser só `cout` ou `cin`, tem várias outras formas possíveis de usar esse mecanismo.

Embora isso parecia uma boa ideia na época, anos 80, e em alguns casos ainda é algo útil, o mecanismo se mostrou problemático e limitado, e em versão mais atual da linguagem está preferindo um mecanismo poderoso de formatação de dados, que eu não vou falar que é igual ao do C, porque é muito melhor, mas o jeitão lembra bem. Pode ver mais na [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) como usá-lo, quase sempre será mais interessante agora e o *stream* será quase um legado.

Os nomes corretos deles são *stream insertion operator* (<<) e *stream extraction operator* (>>), portanto mesmo que o símbolo seja o mesmo não pode ser confundido com outros operadores existentes, e esse é um dos motivos que isso é ruim.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).