# Pra que serve o BufferedStream do C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Preciso acumular bytes em um buffer para depois descarregá-los em um arquivo. Usei alguns artifícios para isso mas me disseram que tem um carinha que pode me ajudar, o `BufferedStream`.

Ao instanciá-lo, eu configuro o tamanho do buffer. Por isso, achei que ele daria um "autoflush" toda vez que ele alcançasse o tamanho do buffer especificado. Porém, isso não ocorre, e ele fica acumulando até eu mandar que ele execute o flush.

Testei o caso onde coloquei o buffer com capacidade de 128 bytes e carreguei nele 192 bytes, ele não fez nada.

Gostaria de saber como esse `BufferedStream` funciona. Qual o sentido dele pedir um bufferSize sendo que ele não o usa pra nada?

Answer (score 4):

Seguindo a documentação aqui: [https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.bufferedstream](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.bufferedstream?view=net-5.0)

> Adiciona uma camada de armazenamento em buffer para ler e gravar
> operações em outro fluxo
> ....
> Um buffer é um bloco de bytes na memória usado para armazenar dados em cache, reduzindo > assim o número de chamadas para o sistema operacional. Os buffers melhoram o desempenho > de leitura e gravação

Em resumo, uma classe para fazer buffer de um stream e melhorar as operações de leitura e escrita.

Sobre suas dúvidas:
*"Testei o caso onde coloquei o buffer com capacidade de 128 bytes e carreguei nele 192 bytes, ele não fez nada"* e *"Qual o sentido dele pedir um bufferSize sendo que ele não o usa pra nada?"*

Nesse caso não entendeu bem o funcinamento do parâmetro de size do classe `BufferedStream`. Veja a documentação, primeiro sobre o parâmetro no construtor: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.bufferedstream.-ctor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.bufferedstream.-ctor?view=net-5.0)

> A shared read/write buffer is allocated the first time a
> BufferedStream object is initialized with this constructor. The shared
> buffer is not used if all reads and writes are greater than or equal
> to bufferSize.

Ou, em tradução livre

> Um buffer de leitura / gravação compartilhado é alocado na primeira
> vez que um objeto BufferedStream é inicializado com este construtor. O
> buffer compartilhado não é usado se todas as leituras e gravações
> forem maiores ou iguais a bufferSize

Ou seja, esse parâmetro serve para definir o tamanho do buffer interno, chamado aqui de "compartilhado", usado pela classe `BufferedStream`.

Ainda no link da documentação, após um exemplo de código tem:

> Se você sempre ler e gravar para tamanhos maiores que o tamanho do
> buffer interno, BufferedStream talvez nem mesmo aloque o buffer
> interno.

Ou seja, você inicializou a classe com um buffer size de 128, mas usou 192, logo o buffer interno sequer foi usado, e o parâmetro não fez sentido.

Inclusive no link da documentação, tem um exemplo de código e uma sugestão para testar esse parâmetro para determinar a melhor combinação em relação a parformance:

> Varie as constantes `dataArraySize` e `streamBufferSize` para exibir
> seu efeito sobre o desempenho.

Em resumo, o parâmetro de `bufferSize` serve para definir o tamanho do buffer interno e otimizar mais as operações.

Answer (score 2):

Esta classe existe basicamente para criar uma técnica de [*double buffer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering) quando ela é necessária em algum cenário, ou para uso em conjunto com alguma [*stream*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49831/101) que não é *bufferizado* e você precisa disso.

Se você usa uma classe de *stream* *bufferizada*, que eu acho que é o caso de todas as padrões contidas na BCL do .NET (pelo menos nas que fazem sentido ter um *buffer*), não precisa usar esta classe, portanto eu me preocuparia pouco com ela, provavelmente está querendo usar algo que não é necessário, ou em algum caso bem avançado, que não há indicação na pergunta.

No passado ela foi mais útil quando a *bufferização* não era aplicada em diversas classes.

Se realmente precisar, não for um erro de *design*, e tiver algum problema específico poderá fazer uma pergunta com esse problema com todas informações necessárias.

Se estiver curioso pode consultar o [fonte da classe](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/BufferedStream.cs,7ee3b8c340d71eb3).

Não vou colocar a documentação porque este é um caso que ela não serve muito, afinal ela está defasada, ninguém foi lá mudar para identificar que a classe é quase obsoleta.